# jquery alert($("window").height() + " " + $("document").height() + " " +$("window").width()); returns all values as null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the height and width of the browser widow so it returns null the example code is below
I also used $("window").load(function())  that I found in stackoverflow and still it returns null.

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></scipt>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        //$("#page").outerWidth($("window").width(),true);
        // $("#page").outerHeight($("window").height(),true);
        alert($("window").height() + " " + $("document").height() + " " +$("window").width());
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$("tagthatdoesnotexist").height()` also returns null. odd. `</sarcasm>`

Comment: What makes this question worse is the fact that you already have `$(document).ready`, and yet you still try `$("document")`...

Comment: Also you should close the line that includes jQuery properly by using `</script>` instead of `</scipt>` (maybe the browser is smart enough to know that before `<script>`, a `</script>` goes so it works it in the same fashion as `<li>` does).

Answer (score 4):

`$("window")` should be `$(window)`.

When you use `$("window")`, you're asking jQuery to select all elements with the tagName "window" (and there aren't any).  When you use `$(window)`, you're actually telling jQuery to wrap the `window` object.

And, just to be clear, this applies to `$("document")` vs. `$(document)` change as well.

Comment: Thanks that helped and my apologies for the typo in the post this is my first question on stackoverflow and I had a difficult time posting code.

Comment: No worries about the typo.

Answer (score 0):

This is it:

```
$(document).ready(
                   function () {

                       //$("#page").outerWidth($("window").width(),true);
                       // $("#page").outerHeight($("window").height(),true);
                       alert($(window).height() + " " + $(document).height() + " " + $(window).width());

                   }

                      );
```